# Float the nav to the right and keep it flush with the edge of the page on resize

Tags: css, css-float, width, nav

I need the  menu (book 1, book 2 etc) that is wrapped in the div class="nav" to float all the way right and stay aligned and sticky to the right side of the browser window no matter how big the monitor size.

Do I need to use 100% width on one of the elements above this nav or maybe to the body?

http://www.kailasphotography.com/new/1.html

http://www.kailasphotography.com/new/css/main.css

Any help would be great! thanks

Comment: it's looks floated to the right and works perfectly, where is the problem??

Comment: position:fixed; along with the x and y will follow the scroll. It will require that you add some padding to your body to take up the space where the menu is now. Learn about fixed position

Comment: @MujtabaFathel It is floated right but if you scroll the main image to the left the menu moves along with it and I want to keep it in place and always stay there no matter the resize or the screen size

Comment: @BootstrapThemer can you elaborate on the x and y css code?

Comment: .yourselector {position:fixed;right:10px;top:10px} will always be at the top right 10px in and from the right but will be out of the document flow, read up on position:fixed and other basics. When you scroll it will scroll with the page and as you resize it will stick there.

Comment: @BootstrapThemer I was able to achieve the desired style by adding in top: 5% along with the float: fixed and it works like a charm. Thanks for the direction